# GIT ignore a file during checkout

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a Jenkins file in the Master branch (Main GIT repo) which gets triggered whenever a code is merged to Master. Now everytime when a develop branch (local copy for development) is cloned from the Master the Jenkins build is triggered from the local copy which I need to stop. So I want the file to be ignored whenever a develop branch is created but should be retained in the Master.

Just wondering if there is a way for it. Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many times do you clone?

Comment: It is not just me, The whole team (5 ppl) clone from the Master to create their respective develop branches and then when development is done we merge it back to the Master. So the clone happens at least once in a day.

Comment: Do you mean pull? Normally you only clone once per repo

Comment: So, you somehow automatically start build from _any_ clone, not just from the main repository? How it is even possible, without some special efforts? If you do it intentionally, why you do it?

Comment: By cloning do you mean branching off master to create a new development branch?

Comment: Yes. It's branching off master to create a new dev branch.